# Revelation 1:8 declares that Jesus Christ is God Almighty, on what Biblical basis do the Jehovah Witnesses deny this declaration?

Tags: biblical-basis, jehovahs-witnesses, revelation

We read at Revelation 1:4, "John to the seven churches that are in Asia; Grace to you and peace, FROM HIM who is and who was and who is to come; and from the seven Spirits who are before HIS throne," So who is the "HIM" and who is the "HIS" in this verse? The eternal God.

Verse 5, "and from Jesus Christ, the faithful witness, the first-born of the dead, and the ruler of the kings of the earth. To Him who loves us and released us from our sins by His blood." From this verse it is obviously Jesus Christ.

At verse 6 where He/Jesus Christ has made us to be a kingdom, priests to His God and Father was one of the reasons Jesus incarnated as a man. He not only released us from our sins by His blood, (vs5) but He also (as a man) presented us to His God and His Father.

Verse 7, "Behold, He is coming, with the clouds, and every eye will see Him, even those who pierced Him, and all the tribes of the earth will mourn over Him. Even so, Amen.

Remember, at verse 4, I stated the "Him" is the eternal God. You cannot assume it's the Father because the Father does not qualify as coming in the clouds and because you cannot see the person of God the Father.

Revelation 1:8, "I am the Alpha and the Omega," says the Lord God, who is and who was and who is to come, the Almighty."

Verse 17, "And when I saw Him, (saw who?) I fell at His feet as a dead man. And He laid His right hand upon me, saying, "Do not be afraid, I am the first and the last, vs18, and the living One, and I was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore, and I have the keys of death and Hades."

Since we know the various text identify Jesus Christ as coming in the clouds, and every eye will see Him (vs8) He must be "God Almighty" and not just a "mighty" god as the Jehovah Witnesses teach. Revelation 22:12-13 also confirms that Jesus Christ is both the Alpha and Omega and the first and the last, the beginning and the end."

The Apostle John closes out the book of Revelation at verses 20, "He who testifies to these things says, "Yes, I am coming quickly." Amen, COME LORD JESUS.

I'm going to add some new information from the jw.org site by quoting the following:

> While Jesus Christ is referred to in the previous verse as “coming with the clouds,” the words of Revelation 1:8 and the surrounding verses show that he could not be “the Alpha and the Omega.” In the Scriptures, only the Father of the Lord Jesus Christ is spoken of as “the Lord God” and as the “Almighty.”

Please note in this statement that, only the Father" of the Lord Jesus Christ is spoken of in Revelation 1:8. This is an "assumption" on their part. The word "Father" nowhere appears in Revelation 1:8.

At verse 4 it specifically says, "Grace to you and peace, from HIM who is and who was and is to come." verse 5, and from Jesus Christ etc. As I stated the "HIM" is the eternal God who is God Almighty. I think the following example of what I mean can be explained from Genesis 1:26-27.

Verse 26, "The God said," notice it does not refer to any particular person. It then says, "Let US make man in OUR image." Whatever argument that can be made regarding who the "Us" and the "Our" is really beside the point, why?

Genesis 1:27, "And God created man in "His" own image, in the image of God "He" created him; male and female He created them." In this verse the "His" and the "He" refers to God, and only God, not some specific person.

The same is true at Revelation 1:4, "Grace and peace from "HIM" who is and who was and who is to come; and from the seven Spirits who are before "HIS" throne;" Revelation 4:8-10 identifies the Lord God, the Almighty is on the throne.

Comment: **You** declare that revelation 1:8 is Jesus declaring himself to be God Almighty.   We disagree and say it is Jehovah who is God Almighty in vs 8.    https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/alpha-omega/

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2737/11555.   Who is speaking at revelation 1:8?

Comment: The problem in answer a question like this that an individual is primed with an answer due to what they have been taught. The trinitarian will say "Yes, Jesus is the Alpha and the Omega" while the non-trinitarian will say "No, only Jehovah is the Alpha and the Omega". Both will see their answer/explanation as true based on what they were taught. The only way for the individual to see the other side is if God reveals it.

Comment: This question should be shortened to exclude the rebuttal issues it has posted within it! This is not a forum, but a question and answer site. We should strive to avoid discussions and debates within posts.

Comment: @agarza  there is no problem answering a question that is honestly   seeking to know what denomination X teaches about z.  However a question like this one that is full of prebuttal is difficult because now an answer has to delve too many side points.  And then there is the  less than universally accepted assertion that rev1:8 is Jesus taking on the title of Almighty God

Comment: @KenGraham Why Ken? At the bottom it does say, "Answer Your Question?"

Comment: @Kris You made this comment. You declare that revelation 1:8 is Jesus declaring himself to be God Almighty. We disagree and say it is Jehovah who is God Almighty" I "DO NOT" disagree that it is Jehovah God who is God Almighty. And I proved it. In fact, I will edit my thread and show you the proof.

Comment: @Mr.Bond  don’t edit your question to do anymore pontificating. Instead follow the moderators request to simply ask a question from JWs and wait for an answer. Leave out all of your prebuttal. If you want to expound on what you believe ask a question in a way that your beliefs are the correct answer then place your answer in the answer section under your question.

Comment: Please [edit] this to be more concise and to remove your rebuttal.

Comment: @curiousdannii Can you please do it for me? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank You!

Comment: I have significant issue with a moderator belonging to the very denomjnation against whom this question poses a doctrinal falsehood, is given the power to close said question. That is a factual and significant breach of conflict of interest laws (which all forums are also bound by) particularly in light of other questions being directly edited, this O.P asking for any edits to this question where necessary, a point ignored and the question simply closed off in order to avoid public discussion on the matter (to reduce google rankings of this topic). Moderators should be very careful of this

Comment: @Adam Just a little note: This is **not** a forum, but a question and answer site.  Questions and answers are to be posted in a factual form and not on the points of a forum of discussion or debate.

Comment: @Adam It was not closed because of any theological position, but because it is too long and not focused enough. Questions should not contain a dozen rebuttals against possible answers.